# Pandas read (Excel) cells, and return looked up values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A column in Excel file shows the short-form of some descriptions. They are one-to-one relationship in a dictionary.

I want to look them up each, and write the looked up values to a new file, side by side with the short forms.

Xlrd and xlwt are basic so I used them:

```
product_dict = {
"082" : "Specified brand(s)",
"035" : "Well known brand",
"069" : "Brandless ",
"054" : "Good middle class restaurant",
"062" : "Modest class restaurant"}

import xlwt, xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\\file.xlsx")
old_sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='cp1252', style_compression = 0)
sheet = book.add_sheet('Sheet1', cell_overwrite_ok = True)

for row_index in range(1, old_sheet.nrows):
    new_list = []   
    Cell_a = str(old_sheet.cell(row_index, 0).value)

    for each in Cell_a.split(", "):

        new_list.append(product_dict[each])

    sheet.write(row_index, 0, Cell_a)
    sheet.write(row_index, 1, "; ".join(new_list))

book.save("C:\\files-1.xls")
```

It looks ok. But I want to learn the Pandas way to do the same.

How does the Pandas way looked like, in addition to below? Thank you.

```
data = {'Code': ["082","069","054"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

Comment: can you also post the raw data in text form (or a code to reproduce the dataframe)and the dictionary? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lookup dictionary in the form of a python dictionary, you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd

lookup_dict = {'1': 'item_1', '2':'item_2'}

# Create example dataframe
df_to_process = pd.DataFrame()
df_to_process['code'] = ['1, 2', '1', '2']

# Use .apply and lambda function to split 'code' and then do a lookup on each item
df_to_process['code_items'] = df_to_process['code'].apply(lambda x: '; '.join([lookup_dict[code] for code in x.replace(' ','').split(',')]))
```

With your examples:

```
import pandas as pd

product_dict = {
"082" : "Specified brand(s)",
"035" : "Well known brand",
"069" : "Brandless ",
"054" : "Good middle class restaurant",
"062" : "Modest class restaurant"}

data = {'Code': ["082","069","054"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['code_items'] = df['Code'].apply(lambda x: '; '.join([product_dict[code] for code in x.replace(' ','').split(',')]))
```

Answer (score 1):

With the data given, I would first [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) the dictionary to a new column, then [`aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) with `','.join`:

```
final=df.assign(New=df.Code.map(product_dict)).agg(','.join).to_frame().T
```

---

```
          Code                                                New
0  082,069,054  Specified brand(s),Brandless ,Good middle clas...
```

Where:

```
print(df.assign(New=df.Code.map(product_dict)))
```

is:

```
  Code                           New
0  082            Specified brand(s)
1  069                    Brandless 
2  054  Good middle class restaurant
```

Comment: thank you for the teaching! hope you don't mind I choose the ealier answer for it's a little easier to me. :)